# Как создать bat файл с помощью c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, bat

Необходимо создать bat файл а дальше записать в него программный. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать, желательно привести пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ofstream of("test.bat");
of << "@echo off" << endl;
of << "echo Hello, world!" << endl;
of << "dir" << endl;
of.close();
system("test.bat");
```

Вы примерно этого хотели?